# Combine 3 images

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have the HDRI for the sky in the background, the background image as the ground plane and the render.

I struggle to combine the background and the HDRI and add the both as a bacground for the render.

How do I combine 3 images in the compositor?
[image]

Comment: Maybe try alpha in the factor?

Comment: @Ebi it doesn't work.

Comment: Would be useful to get the source file to view the project, it is quite hard to know just from a screenshot